# Error while running mysql_secure_installation on arch linux

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, arch

I'm trying to install MySQL(pure) on Arch Linux so I downloaded the following file from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/.

```
mysql-8.0.26-linux-glibc2.17-x86_64-minimal-rebuild.tar.xz
```

I extracted it and tried to run ./mysql_secure_installation but after I enter the root password I get the following error message:

```
[rob@archrob bin]$ sudo ./mysql_secure_installation 

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

How can I fix this?

---

I tried to download it from AUR repository too but when I run the makepkg -si it get a point of the installation it looks like will take forever.

Build files have benn written to /home/rob/mysql/src/build

```
[0%] Built target INFO_BIN
[0%] built target abi_check
[0%] built target INFO_SRC
[0%] Building CXX object extra/protobuf...
[0%] and so on...
```

After one hour it was at [22%] so I stopped the installation and tried from the official website.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start mariadb before running `mysql_secure_installation`:

```sh
$ sudo systemctl start mariadb.service
```